# FirebaseUIAuth import is casuing conflict

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/firebase_ui_auth.dart:14:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'src/providers/auth_provider.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/widgets/reauthenticate_dialog.dart:8:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/flows/phone_auth_flow.dart:96:7: Error: Class 'PhoneAuthFlow' inherits multiple members named 'provider' with incompatible signatures.
Try adding a declaration of 'provider' to 'PhoneAuthFlow'.
class PhoneAuthFlow extends AuthFlow<PhoneAuthProvider>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/auth_flow.dart:49:9: Context: This is one of the overridden members.
  T get provider => _provider..authListener = this;
        ^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart:45:20: Context: This is one of the overridden members.
  AuthProvider get provider;
                   ^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/flows/phone_auth_flow.dart:165:14: Error: The method 'onCredentialReceived' isn't defined for the class 'PhoneAuthProvider'.
 - 'PhoneAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'onCredentialReceived'.
    provider.onCredentialReceived(credential, action);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/widgets/different_method_sign_in_dialog.dart:8:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/widgets/auth_flow_builder.dart:230:16: Error: A value of type 'PhoneAuthProvider' can't be returned from a function with return type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>'.
 - 'PhoneAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
        return PhoneAuthProvider();
               ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/widgets/auth_flow_builder.dart:232:16: Error: A value of type 'UniversalEmailSignInProvider' can't be returned from a function with return type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>'.
 - 'UniversalEmailSignInProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/universal_email_sign_in_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/universal_email_sign_in_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
        return UniversalEmailSignInProvider();
               ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/widgets/auth_flow_builder.dart:256:19: Error: The argument type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'EmailLinkAuthProvider'.
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
 - 'EmailLinkAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart').
        provider: provider,
                  ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/widgets/auth_flow_builder.dart:267:19: Error: The argument type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PhoneAuthProvider'.
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
 - 'PhoneAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart').
        provider: provider,
                  ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/widgets/auth_flow_builder.dart:273:19: Error: The argument type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UniversalEmailSignInProvider'.
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
 - 'UniversalEmailSignInProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/universal_email_sign_in_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/universal_email_sign_in_provider.dart').
        provider: provider,
                  ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/views/login_view.dart:238:29: Error: The argument type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'EmailLinkAuthProvider'.
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
 - 'EmailLinkAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart').
                  provider: provider,
                            ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/views/email_link_sign_in_view.dart:51:24: Error: The argument type 'EmailLinkAuthProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>?'.
 - 'EmailLinkAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
      provider: widget.provider,
                       ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/screens/universal_email_sign_in_screen.dart:68:21: Error: The getter 'providerId' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'providerId'.
            element.providerId: element,
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/screens/universal_email_sign_in_screen.dart:68:33: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
            element.providerId: element,
                                ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/screens/internal/multi_provider_screen.dart:7:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/screens/profile_screen.dart:745:61: Error: The getter 'providerId' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'providerId'.
        .where((provider) => user.isProviderLinked(provider.providerId))
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/screens/profile_screen.dart:755:47: Error: The getter 'providerId' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'providerId'.
              !user.isProviderLinked(provider.providerId) &&
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/screens/profile_screen.dart:756:24: Error: The method 'supportsPlatform' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'supportsPlatform'.
              provider.supportsPlatform(platform),
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/screens/internal/provider_screen.dart:7:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/universal_email_sign_in_provider.dart:7:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart:8:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart:75:5: Error: The getter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'PhoneAuthProvider'.
 - 'PhoneAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'auth'.
    auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    ^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart:102:7: Error: The method 'onCredentialReceived' isn't defined for the class 'PhoneAuthProvider'.
 - 'PhoneAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'onCredentialReceived'.
      onCredentialReceived(credential, action);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart:118:52: Error: The getter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'PhoneAuthProvider'.
 - 'PhoneAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'auth'.
    bool shouldLink = action == AuthAction.link || auth.currentUser != null;
                                                   ^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart:121:16: Error: The getter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'PhoneAuthProvider'.
 - 'PhoneAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'auth'.
      result = auth.currentUser!.linkWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
               ^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart:123:16: Error: The getter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'PhoneAuthProvider'.
 - 'PhoneAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'auth'.
      result = auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
               ^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart:8:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart:54:20: Error: The getter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'EmailLinkAuthProvider'.
 - 'EmailLinkAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'auth'.
    final future = auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
                   ^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart:67:9: Error: The getter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'EmailLinkAuthProvider'.
 - 'EmailLinkAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'auth'.
    if (auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(link)) {
        ^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart:89:5: Error: The getter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'EmailLinkAuthProvider'.
 - 'EmailLinkAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/email_link_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'auth'.
    auth
    ^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/navigation/authentication.dart:8:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/mfa.dart:49:12: Error: The setter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'PhoneAuthProvider'.
 - 'PhoneAuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/phone_auth_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'auth'.
  provider.auth = auth ?? FirebaseAuth.instance;
           ^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/flows/universal_email_sign_in_flow.dart:23:7: Error: Class 'UniversalEmailSignInFlow' inherits multiple members named 'provider' with incompatible signatures.
Try adding a declaration of 'provider' to 'UniversalEmailSignInFlow'.
class UniversalEmailSignInFlow extends AuthFlow<UniversalEmailSignInProvider>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/auth_flow.dart:49:9: Context: This is one of the overridden members.
  T get provider => _provider..authListener = this;
        ^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart:45:20: Context: This is one of the overridden members.
  AuthProvider get provider;
                   ^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/flows/universal_email_sign_in_flow.dart:44:14: Error: The method 'findProvidersForEmail' isn't defined for the class 'UniversalEmailSignInProvider'.
 - 'UniversalEmailSignInProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/universal_email_sign_in_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/universal_email_sign_in_provider.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'findProvidersForEmail'.
    provider.findProvidersForEmail(email);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/flows/email_link_flow.dart:33:7: Error: Class 'EmailLinkFlow' inherits multiple members named 'provider' with incompatible signatures.
Try adding a declaration of 'provider' to 'EmailLinkFlow'.
class EmailLinkFlow extends AuthFlow<EmailLinkAuthProvider>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/auth_flow.dart:49:9: Context: This is one of the overridden members.
  T get provider => _provider..authListener = this;
        ^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart:45:20: Context: This is one of the overridden members.
  AuthProvider get provider;
                   ^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/auth_flow.dart:11:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart'.
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/auth_flow.dart:49:9: Error: The return type of the method 'AuthFlow.provider' is 'T', which does not match the return type, 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>', of the overridden method, 'AuthListener.provider'.
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
Change to a subtype of 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>'.
  T get provider => _provider..authListener = this;
        ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart:45:20: Context: This is the overridden method ('provider').
  AuthProvider get provider;
                   ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/auth_flow.dart:163:26: Error: The argument type 'T' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>' because 'T' is nullable and 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>' isn't.
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.7.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.0.4/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
      defaultOnAuthError(provider, error);
                         ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\SDKs\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I was trying to use the *firebase_ui_auth* package which includes the *ForgotPasswordScreen* feature. But whenever I use the *firebase_ui_auth* package I get th above.

I am not importing any other firease auth package in this particular file, I am only importing the *firebase_ui_auth* package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `
//  Flutter imports:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//  Package imports:
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart' as fui
    show ForgotPasswordScreen;

class ForgotPasswordScreenMain extends StatelessWidget {
  const ForgotPasswordScreenMain({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const fui.ForgotPasswordScreen();
  }
}
`

Comment: Please don't add required details in comments, instead, [edit] the question to include them. Make sure you also take the [tour] and read [ask].